# GitLab: How can I programatically download the artifacts issued at end of CI pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab, how can I programatically download the artifacts issued at end of a CI pipeline?

It is easy to download it via the UI but how can I get it through API? In other words, is it possible to access it via a token or something similar?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is possible through the API as in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#get-job-artifacts

> GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id/artifacts

Example requests:

- Using the PRIVATE-TOKEN header:

  ```
   curl --location --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/8/artifacts"
  ```
- Using the JOB-TOKEN header (only inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`):

  ```
   curl --location --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/8/artifacts"
  ```
- Using the `job_token` parameter (only inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`):

  ```
   curl --location --form "job-token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/8/artifacts"
  ```

Comment: If using namespaced API calls, make sure that the NAMESPACE/PROJECT_PATH is URL-encoded. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#namespaced-path-encoding

Comment: Is it correct that GitLab is actively blocking downloads of artifacts on the Free Plan with private tokens? I just cannot seem to find a way to authenticate to download an artifact, but I can authenticate for everything else (including the REST API) just fine.

Comment: @dummdidumm right now, for me the JOB-TOKEN works - most important is to really use the API, so /api/v4/projects.... to access the files. It does not work with project/ref - this is limited to premium and upwards. At least right now

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

GITLAB_URL="https://gitlab.example.com"
GITLAB_ARTIFACT_TOKEN="<token>"
group="<group>"
project="<project>"
branch="<branch>"
job="<job>"

outZipFile="$project.zip"
outHeadersFile="$outZipFile.httpheaders"

etagArgs=()
# The following is unfortunately not yet supported by GitLab; the returned Etag never changes:
#if [[ -f "$outHeadersFile" ]] && [[ -f "$outZipFile" ]]; then
#  etag=$(grep etag < "$outHeadersFile" | cut -f2 -d' ')
#  if [[ -n "$etag" ]]; then
#    etagArgs=("--header" "If-None-Match: $etag")
#    echo "using etag: $etag"
#  fi
#fi

response=$(curl "$GITLAB_URL/api/v4/projects/${group}%2F${project}/jobs/artifacts/$branch/download?job=$job" \
  --silent \
  -w "%{http_code}\n" \
  -D "$outHeadersFile" \
  -o "$outZipFile.tmp" \
  --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: $GITLAB_ARTIFACT_TOKEN" \
  "${etagArgs[@]}")

if [[ "$response" == 4* ]] || [[ "$response" == 5* ]]; then
  echo "ERROR - Http status: $response"
  rm "$outZipFile.tmp"
  exit 1
elif [[ "$response" == 304 ]]; then
  echo "$project is up-to-date"
else
  echo "update $outZipFile"
  mv "$outZipFile.tmp" "$outZipFile"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

1. Created a new personal access token with API scopes.
2. Use the token to download it via curl command as shown below.

```sh
curl --location --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:MY_PRIVATE_TOKEN" "https://it-gitlab.cloud.net/api/v4/projects/projectId/jobs/jobId/artifacts" --output watcher
```

Comment: This API works for the *Free Plan*, but are you actually able to download the artifacts themselves? From my observations, the private token, even if given full access, is insufficient to actually download an artifact file when using the GitLab Free Plan.

Comment: The API that I tried is from Gitlab on-premise Enterprise edition & it worked for me. I was able to download the artifacts itself.