# How can I download gitlab CI/CD artifacts with curl?

Tags: git, curl, continuous-integration, gitlab

Our gitlab CI/CD web interface lets us download "artifacts" (e.g. executables, shared libraries) after a successful run, as in the screenshot below:

[image]

---

**Question: Is there a way the artifact can be downloaded from a shell?**  (solution using curl is preferred)

The "`Copy Link Location`" right-click menu option gives me something like `https://git.my_company.com/namespace/project/-/jobs/987134/artifacts/download` so I tried the following:

```
$ curl -O -L https://git.my_company.com/namespace/project/-/jobs/987134/artifacts/download
```

But that doesn't download the right thing: it gives me a vomit of html, but I'm expecting a .zip file.

If I try to download the file from the web UI, the filename defaults to `artifacts.zip`, so I also tried:

```
$ curl -O -L https://git.my_company.com/namespace/project/-/jobs/987134/artifacts/download/artifacts.zip
```

That does *create* a file named `artifacts.zip` but it's still not the expected file: it's still html, though different from the first described attempt.

Comment: I've created a shot shell script, which you can find here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65608447/4291264

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is described here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-artifacts

The structure of the URL to download the whole artifacts archive is the following:

```
https://example.com/<namespace>/<project>/-/jobs/artifacts/<ref>/download?job=<job_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

For public repository,

Go to `Settings > General > Permissions > Pipelines must be "Everyone with access".`