# Overwriting a file from GitLab using curl

Tags: curl, gitlab, put, overwrite

I need to overwrite a GitLab file with a new content using curl. The GET request is working as expected, but I have issues with the PUT request to replace the content of the file.

The following link returns successfully the content of the file in the browser:

`https://<GITLAB-URL>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/repository/files/<FILENAME>/raw/?ref\=master`

This is the curl request which is failing to copy the content of FILE-CONTENT.txt into TARGET-FILE.txt. It returns a `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error message.

`curl -v --request PUT --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:<READ-WRITE-API-TOKEN>" -F "branch=master" -F "author_email=email" -F "author_name=me" -F "content=</PATH/FILE-CONTENT.txt>" -F "commit_message=TEST" " https://<GITLAB-URL>/api/v4/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/repository/files/<TARGET-FILE.txt>/raw/?ref\=master"`

Please advise what is the correct method and syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure I understand your question correctly:
Are you trying to modify a file within your repository by using curl in a automatic pipeline?

If that is the case, I would argue this is not intended. If you want to copy the content of a file that was generated in an automatic pipeline, you mark it as an [artifact](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) in `CI` file. The artifact can then be accessed via curl.

If you just want to modify the file within a script I don't see why you would not just use `git commit` + `git push` using the read-write acces token.

**EDIT**:
First, copy the contents to the target file within the pipeline-job and expose it as an artifact by modifying your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
      - # Process that creates FILE-CONTENT.txt
      - cp <path-to>/FILE-CONTENT.txt /TARGET.txt      
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - /TARGET.txt
```

Then use curl and the job API, as described [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/job_artifacts.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837426/gitlab-how-can-i-programatically-download-the-artifacts-issued-at-end-of-ci-pip). To check wether the artifacts have been correctly created, you can also navigate to the job in the CI/CD Ribbon of the Web UI, there should be a button to download and browse the artifacts.

Comment: Jonathan, that's correct I'm trying to modify my file from my GitLab repository using curl. Please clarify your 2nd paragraph as I didn't understand. Did you mean that my request is not possible? Also, FYI, the curl request I'm trying to figure out will run from a Lambda function in AWS and I'm trying to avoid using git commands. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Hey Alex, the conceptual problem I tried to hint at in the second problem is the following: If the pipeline is triggered by a push event, another push event inside the job basically would recursively trigger the pipeline. So changing version controlled files from within the pipeline is not recommendable

Comment: The 3rd paragraph regards the fundamental concept of git version control. If you change a file that belongs to a repository, the changes should allways be applied to the remote server via git as they should be captured by git. So I think it is probably not possible to change a tracked file via curl on server side. If you could specify the purpose of the file that you want to change, maybe I can say more on how I would do it (e.g. is it a documentation). Cheers

Comment: Jonathan, this file (FILE-CONTENT.txt) holds a token that will be updated every 24 hours and need to be copied into TARGET.txt.

Comment: And I assume this token is subsequently downloaded by another script via e.g. curl? This sounds very much like the `TARGET.txt` should be exposed as a pipeline-artifact. Artifacts can be accessed via the web-UI as well as via curl. If that sounds reasonable I'll set up an answer with the corresponding sources and example code.

Comment: Please share the code to take a look, it sounds pretty much what I need.